# Server or online DB for login in lua

Tags: authentication, server, lua

I'm writing an application in `lua` using `Corona simulator` and i'm facing a problem due to my complete lack of knowledge in the subject. I need users to be able to login to my app but i have complete ignorance on what's the best/safest way to do it. Should i use an online database (if that's possible) or a `server`? If i should use a `server` can someone point me to the right direction?

This is my first time working with login forms and i would be grateful if you could point me in the right direction. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you experiment with [Google Firebase](https://firebase.google.com). I have used it to set up a real-time database instance for login authentication and accessed it via Lua code. They offer plenty of documentation on secure access, etc.

Since you are apparently new to all of this, I’d suggest you take it slow. First, understand how to establish communication with the database instance, and then look carefully into security best practices before opening up your application to real users with potentially sensitive information.